# Comparing objects of resources using ResourceManager.GetObject()

Tags: c#, .net

According to my tests, ResourceManager.GetObject() never returns the same reference to object, instead always a different one, when called with the same arguments.

I want to compare my Images by references.

Can I use wrapper like "Images"?:

```
// designer of resources:

    internal class Resources {
        internal static Bitmap tick {
            get {
                object obj = ResourceManager.GetObject("tick");
                return ((Bitmap)(obj));
            }
        }
    }

// my wrapper:

    internal class Images
    {
        private static Bitmap _tick;

        internal static Bitmap tick
        {
            get { return _tick ?? (_tick = Resources.tick); }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Of course, you need to make sure `_tick` is not disposed also :)

Comment: Bitmaps are *very* expensive objects, they normally eat a huge amount of memory for their pixel data.  Keeping one permanently referenced for the life of the program is a very high price to pay.  Doing this is almost always wrong.

Comment: It's not a problem because I want to compare only a few images 16*16.